# Is there a such thing as a quasi-random shuffle?

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, random, monte-carlo

I've recently experimented with [Quasi-random numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence) in monte-carlo applications. Is there a way to construct a quasi-random shuffle? By that I mean can I take a sequence $Q$ and shuffle it to produce a sequence $S$ where $\frac{1}{j} \sum_{i=1}^{j} f(S_i)$ converges to the whole-sequence mean faster than a random shuffle.

Apologies in advance if I got the notation wrong up there, I'm not a mathematician.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the approach presented in the paper [Quasi-Random resamplings, with applications to rule-samplng, cross-validation and (su-)bagging](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00113368/en). Additionally if feasible I would suggest keeping track of previous draws, as repetitions might arise before the whole set of permutations is exhausted.

Depending on the form of your function (e.g. if there is a nonuniform relationship among coordinates) better methods could also be devised.